# disable submit button for some options in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here I am trying to disable submit button for the options dropdown which satisfies my condition. But it disables for everything. 
Can anyone help this out?
thanks in advance

```
     for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
      if(a[i] == "string") {
         $('#option/>).val(a[i]).appendTo('#select').css('color','red');
         $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);    }
      else {
         $('#option/>).val(a[i]).appendTo('#select').css('color','black');
         $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);    }
```

Comment: What do you mean **disables everything**? Also put your HTML code please.

Comment: It disables Button for every option in select

Answer (score 0):

If the last item of a equals the "string", then the `#submit` will be disabled.
And also try to use `removeAttr('disabled')` and not assign false to it.